# Trying to Parse .txt file to get file in Desired form for further data analys

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I need to do some data analysis to the following datasets using python and pandas. But I am running into the problem of separating the heading "Daily means        Year 1977        site 2917401 SG. LANGAT at KAJANG,SELANGOR
Stage m" as when I read the data this heading also comes up in the dataframe. So any tips on how I can remove the heading and structure the data such way that would beneficial to my analysis.

Daily means        Year 1977        site 2917401 SG. LANGAT at KAJANG,SELANGOR
Stage m

```
 Day      Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec

   1    22.98   22.81   22.74   22.50   22.73   22.84   22.67   22.45   22.81   23.58   23.23   23.62
   2    22.99   22.80   22.75   22.51   22.61   22.77   22.67   22.44   22.73   24.17   23.15   23.71
   3    23.02   22.91   22.78   22.47   22.58   22.72   22.71   22.44   22.69   23.62   23.10   23.80
   4    23.26   22.98   22.71   22.45   22.57   22.90   22.90   22.46   22.65   23.62   23.14   23.91
   5    24.29   22.85   22.66   22.65   22.64   23.15   23.02   22.50   22.60   23.48   23.26   23.09
   6    24.07   22.80   22.64   22.55   22.64   23.11   22.88   22.54   22.56   23.95   23.23   22.99
   7    23.44   22.78   22.60   22.54   22.83   23.05   22.92   22.54   22.82   24.33   23.19   23.06
   8    23.30   22.74   22.59   22.57   22.98   23.13   23.13   22.77   22.85   24.48   23.16   23.05
   9    23.20   22.75   22.59   22.57   23.03   22.96   22.92   22.72   22.67   23.95   23.09   23.02
  10    23.21   22.74   22.58   22.60   22.87   22.90   22.86   22.58   22.61   23.74   23.20   23.05
  11    23.22   22.74   22.57   22.53   22.86   23.07   22.80   22.53   22.56   23.86   23.39   22.92
  12    23.17   22.73   22.56   22.53   22.90   22.98   22.75   22.51   22.55   23.51   23.49   22.92
  13    23.24   22.74   22.56   22.66   23.37   23.18   22.72   22.48   22.52   23.43   23.51   22.92
  14    23.10   22.97   22.54   22.69   23.21   22.94   22.82   22.45   22.51   23.41   23.33   22.89
  15    23.05   22.90   22.52   22.62   23.15   23.15   22.74   22.51   22.49   23.39   23.26   22.86
  16    23.01   22.80   22.53   22.80   22.95   23.15   22.68   22.58   22.51   23.61   23.18   22.97
  17    22.98   22.76   22.56   22.73   22.85   23.17   22.63   22.50   22.51   23.72   23.12   23.06
  18    22.95   22.73   22.74   22.66   22.80   23.27   22.62   22.46   22.47   23.81   23.15   23.15
  19    22.94   22.71   22.70   22.62   22.70   23.02   22.57   22.46   22.58   23.53   23.17   22.91
  20    22.92   22.72   22.65   22.60   22.67   22.91   22.57   22.73   22.52   23.47   23.12   22.85
  21    22.90   22.70   22.69   22.68   22.81   22.89   22.54   22.67   22.53   23.51   23.07   22.84
  22    22.89   22.67   22.73   22.72   22.68   22.94   22.53   22.56   22.70   23.42   23.27   22.84
  23    22.91   22.66   22.68   22.61   22.67   22.82   22.52   22.51   22.94   23.37   23.44   22.85
  24    22.89   22.65   22.58   22.65   22.69   22.77   22.50   22.85   22.96   23.30   23.32   22.82
  25    22.86   22.81   22.56   22.64   22.96   22.72   22.47   22.70   23.05   23.37   23.35   22.78
  26    22.84   22.93   22.57   22.55   22.83   22.69   22.46   22.70   23.34   23.40   23.37   22.75
  27    22.85   22.78   22.54   22.65   22.98   22.68   22.45   23.75   23.40   23.40   23.42   22.73
  28    22.85   22.77   22.51   23.08   23.10   22.64   22.47   23.70   23.76   23.35   23.45   22.72
  29    22.84           22.52   22.88   23.18   22.66   22.57   23.20   23.77   23.45   23.54   22.71
  30    22.83           22.61   22.95   23.02   22.66   22.54   23.13   23.48   23.37   23.57   22.72
  31    22.84           22.54           22.93           22.47   22.92           23.28           22.76

 Min    22.83   22.65   22.51   22.45   22.57   22.64   22.45   22.44   22.47   23.28   23.07   22.71     22.44
 Mean   23.09   22.78   22.62   22.64   22.86   22.93   22.68   22.69   22.80   23.61   23.28   23.01     22.92
 Max    24.29   22.98   22.78   23.08   23.37   23.27   23.13   23.75   23.77   24.48   23.57   23.91     24.48
```

Daily means        Year 1978        site 2917401 SG. LANGAT at KAJANG,SELANGOR
Stage m

```
 Day      Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug     Sep     Oct     Nov     Dec

   1    22.72   22.69   22.66   23.21   23.15   22.86   22.61   22.67   22.56   22.58   23.06   22.99
   2    22.70   22.68   22.65   22.94   23.00   22.83   22.61   22.64   22.59   22.86   23.11   22.93
   3    22.68   22.67   22.62   22.85   22.98   22.83   22.73   22.62   22.56   22.76   23.67   22.92
   4    22.65   22.65   22.77   22.82   22.99   22.81   22.73   22.67   22.54   22.65   23.91   22.86
   5    22.63   22.72   22.72   22.89   22.92   22.85   22.66   22.62   22.53   22.60   23.43   22.89
   6    22.62   22.77   22.72   23.21   23.02   23.05   22.77   22.61   22.53   22.60   23.86   22.95
   7    22.61   22.98   22.78   23.12   22.98   22.91   23.02   22.63   22.54   22.54   23.35   23.01
   8    22.81   23.15   22.70   23.69   23.16   23.02   23.06   22.63   22.53   22.49   23.24   22.90
   9    22.81   23.27   22.86   23.40   23.21   22.87   22.89   22.66   22.53   22.48   23.24   22.86
  10    22.79   23.11   22.85   23.13   23.42   22.84   23.13   22.85   22.53   22.49   23.38   22.86
  11    22.70   22.94   22.77   23.18   23.72   22.80   22.87   22.74   22.51   22.56   23.10   22.83
  12    22.86   22.86   22.84   23.41   23.79   22.78   22.87   22.67   22.52   22.56   23.17   22.84
  13    23.18   22.82   22.83   23.39   23.63   22.75   22.95   22.79   22.74   22.69   23.17   22.80
  14    22.86   22.89   22.72   23.20   23.44   22.74   23.01   22.85   22.55   22.59   23.34   22.84
  15    22.86   23.11   22.65   23.11   23.34   22.72   23.12   22.76   22.56   22.53   23.11   22.90
  16    22.85   22.97   22.61   23.20   23.27   22.71   23.24   22.70   22.52   22.68   23.35   22.80
  17    22.99   22.82   22.66   23.15   23.31   22.69   23.03   22.67   22.49   22.73   23.20   22.76
  18    24.01   22.74   23.09   23.38   23.17   22.68   22.94   22.64   22.50   22.75   23.11   22.72
  19    23.75   22.75   22.89   23.67   23.16   22.66   22.95   22.61   22.48   23.07   23.13   22.70
  20    23.25   22.75   22.79   23.50   23.35   22.68   22.87   22.59   22.98   23.60   23.24   22.70
  21    23.12   22.69   23.14   23.25   23.21   22.65   22.95   22.57   22.85   23.62   23.09   22.75
  22    22.99   22.67   23.24   23.14   23.09   22.68   22.96   22.54   22.78   23.34   23.12   23.12
  23    22.92   23.21   23.12   23.06   23.04   22.67   23.36   22.52   22.89   23.10   23.61   23.18
  24    22.87   22.89   23.04   23.33   22.98   22.63   23.76   22.52   23.02   23.07   23.93   22.99
  25    22.86   22.76   22.92   23.51   22.96   22.60   23.26   22.51   22.99   23.18   23.47   22.82
  26    22.82   22.72   22.96   23.44   22.90   22.67   23.09   22.52   22.81   23.87   23.32   22.78
  27    22.79   22.74   22.88   23.42   22.87   22.83   22.98   22.51   22.71   23.62   23.17   22.77
  28    22.78   22.70   22.81   23.18   22.93   22.71   22.90   22.51   22.65   23.37   23.43   22.73
  29    22.76           22.84   23.07   22.94   22.66   22.85   22.51   22.60   23.29   23.19   22.70
  30    22.79           23.02   23.13   22.92   22.63   22.79   22.51   22.57   23.17   23.06   22.69
  31    22.72           23.20           22.87           22.70   22.53           23.12           22.66
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `pandas.read_csv` function and pass you file name, set parameter `skiprows` to skip this undesired row and `skipfooter` to skip min, max rows . You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.read_csv('your_file.txt',skiprows=1,skipfooter=4)
```

or this alternative one might do the same:

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('your_file.txt',header=1,skipfooter=4)
```

More features from read_csv can be found in pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **['skiprows' argument in read_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table)** to skip reading the first line

**EX**:

```
df = pd.read_table("PATH to Text.txt", skiprows=1)
print df
```